# Continuity of translation on $L^1$ on the reals ($\int |f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx\to 0$)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a real valued, Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$. prove

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+t)-f(x)|\, dx=0.$$

I solved it in this way. is it correct?

Since $f(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable function, we can approximate it with step functions $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},f_{4},...$ as follows:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$;

and there exist $N_{0} \in N$ so that

$\sum_{n=N_{0}+1}^{\infty}\int f_{n}(x) dx <\frac{\epsilon}{2} $

Thus we have

$\int \left|f(x+t)-f(x)\right|dx \leq \int \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)(x+t)-\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)\right|dx + \int \left|\sum_{n=N_{0}+1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)(x+t)\right|dx$

$+\int \left|\sum_{n=N_{0}+1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)(x)\right|dx=\int \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)(x+t)-\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)\right|dx+ 2 \int \left|\sum_{n=N_{0}+1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)(x)\right|dx $

$\leq \int \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)(x+t)-\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)\right|dx + \frac{2\epsilon}{2}$

Since $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)$ is a step function, thus

$\lim_{t \to \infty}\int \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)(x+t)-\sum_{n=1}^{N_{0}}f_{n}(x)\right|dx=0$

hence

$\int \left|f(x+t)-f(x)\right|dx \leq \epsilon$ for small enough $t$.

finally, since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we can say

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+t)-f(x)|\, dx=0.$$

Second solution:

Since $f$ is integrable, given $\epsilon>0$, there is a continuous function $h$ vanishing outside a finite integral $[a,b]$ such that $\int \left|f(x)-h(x)\right|dx<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Then
$\int \left|f(x)-f(x+t)\right|dx \leq \int \left|h(x)-h(x+t)\right|dx + \int \left|(f-h)(x)-(f-h)(x+t)\right|dx$.
Now since $h$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$\left|h(x)-h(x+t)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}(b-a)$ whenever $\left|t\right|<\delta$. Thus 
$\int \left|f(x)-f(x+t)\right|dx \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \int \left|f(x)-h(x)\right|dx + \int \left|(f-h)(x)\right|dx+ \int \left|(f-h)(x+t)\right|dx= \frac{\epsilon}{2} +2 \int \left|f(x)-h(x)\right|dx\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} +2\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

Comment: Why exactly does the statement hold for step functions?

Comment: @PhoemueX proposition 14 of chapter lebesgue integral in Royden real analysis says:

Comment: @PhoemueX I thought this is a true. But right now I have doubt. is it correct or not??

Comment: A standard approach is to use the fact that compactly supported continuous functions are dense in $L^1$.

Comment: @gh8498: Yes, it is true. But in the scope of this exercise, I think you should show it. If your step functions have intervals as "steps", this is easy to do. Alternatively, you can use the  hint given by copper.hat and use that the continuous functions with compact support are dense (do you know that?).

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks a lot. I solved it in the second way too that I added to the question. do you mean like that? did I solve it right?

Comment: The second solution looks fine.